# ngDialog not showing modal when clicked and no errors shown on the browser console

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to implement a modal popup in angularjs using ngmodal. The code runs ,there is no error returned on the browser console but nothing happens when the modal is clicked. Below is my attempt and code

Index.html file

```
<html ng-appp="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js">
<script src="ngDialog.js"></script>
<link src="ngDialog.css"></link>
<script src="ngDialog.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <button ng-click="clickToOpen()">My Modal</button>

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId">

        <div id="target" ng-click="test()" ng-controller="tt">
          Click here
        </div>
    </script>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js file

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngDialog']);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope, ngDialog) {

    $scope.clickToOpen = function () {
        ngDialog.open({ template: 'templateId' });
    };

}
function tt($scope)
{
    $scope.test = function()
    {
        console.log("AaA");
    }
}
```

Source of tutorial http://jsfiddle.net/mb6o4yd1/6/
Kindly assist

Answer (score 0):

HTML Page.
You didnt put ng-app

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
 <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/ngDialog.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/app.js"></script>
<link href="Content/ngDialog.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/ngDialog-theme-default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title></title>
</head>
 <body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<button ng-click="clickToOpen()">My Modal</button>
 </div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId">
<div ng-controller="tt" class="ngdialog-message">
    <button ng-click="test()">Click here </button>
</div>
</script>
</div>
```

Here is your app.js

```
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngDialog']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope,ngDialog) {
    $scope.clickToOpen = function () {
       ngDialog.open({
           template: 'templateId'
        });
    };
});
myApp.controller('tt', function ($scope) {
    $scope.test = function () {
        alert('It works');
    }
});
```

Let me know still you find any problem.(I have added ngDialog-theme-default.css )